# Is there a way to make Facebook update open graph data on past shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a webpage that has an updated title & thumbnail every once in a while, couple of times a day.
I would like Facebook to show the updated title/thumbnail when this site is shared. 
I know I can make the facebook **scraper** update it's cache, but it seems to only helps for future shares.
Is there a way to update past shares of the same URL? 
e.g. someone shred my site yesterday when the title was "A", and now I update the title (with the relevant meta tag) to "B" --> so yesterday's post will also show the title "B"

Comment: That's not possible IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The title can't be updated once your URL has been shared by many users (I don't recall the exact amount). The image tag can be updated and when people share it it will be rescraped, or once every 30 days, as Facebook specifies [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update).

Comment: Thanks. but it seems that for a specific share, the title and picture will never change, even if FB re-scrapped the shared URL